# error 400 bad request with AJAX form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, email

JS:

```
function submitForm(){
var data = {
    name: _("#name").value,
    email: _("#email").value,
    message: _("#message").value
}
var output = JSON.stringify(data);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "/src/scripts/parser.php" );
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json'");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            console.log('success')
        } else {
            console.log('fail')
        }

    }
    ajax.send( output );
console.log(output)
```

}

When im trying submit form, i have error:

400 Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Inspect the request using your browser's developer tools to verify that you're posting exactly the data you think you are posting.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is this statement: 'that this server could not understand'. This *usually* indicates that something is wrong on the server. But it could also be that your url is wrong. Either...

1. parser.php does not exist
2. parser.php exists in a different folder (other than 'src/scripts')
3. There is a url re-write module on the server that obfuscates the physical path of parser.php
4. parser.php returns a 400 error

Comment: Thank you! but im change button type from submit to button and work :)